# Gujarati font not displayed correctly

Tags: html

I have written some Gujarati text as follows in html page.

```
Test Prescribbed/તપાસ કરાવવી
```

But the browser shows like

```
Test Prescribed/àª¤àªªàª¾àª¸ àª•àª°àª¾àªµàªµà«€.
```

Please give the solution

Comment: What `charset` you have set in `<meta>` tag?

Comment: <meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: If it still not working. Please post a fiddle or if possible also post screenshot.

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
 <label>test prescribed/તપાસ</label>
</body>
</html>

Output is Test/????

Comment: You have two meta tags with charset attribute. Remove the other which has `charset=ISO-8859-1`. Only use `<meta charset="UTF-8">`. And try

Answer (score 0):

Add **request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");** to your HTML page.

Comment: where to add this in head tag?

Comment: In your scriptlet  (between <% and %> )

Comment: Are you sending data to servlet ?

Comment: no actually i have created one div in javascript and passing the <label for="cid" class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 control-label"><b><u>Test Prescribed/તપાસ કરાવવી</b></u></label> id to javascript.I got on web page like Test Prescribed/???? ??????

Answer (score 0):

Actually gujarati fonts are in `utf-8` format. If you are using **Gujarati** then in your html page following line should be there.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

But you should remove other specifications like if you are using jsp page than

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

line should be removed because you are specifying in meta tag. You need only meta tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your HTML.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```