# Spring Project How to display languages

Tags: java, spring, jsp, maven, spring-mvc

In my spring-mvc project I want to display english language and Hindi language together.example :

```
 Hello Sir, आप कैसे है??  (English language,Hindi language)
```

So,I have 
**style.css**:--

```
  @font-face {  
      font-family: 'kruti dev' ;  
      src: url( '../fonts/k010.ttf' ) format("truetype");  
    } 
.texts {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto;
    font-family: ' kruti dev';

}
```

I have "**message.properties**" on WEB-INF folder. message.properties is:

```
text = Hello Sir,
text_hi=\u0906\u092A \u0915\u0948\u0938\u0947 \u0939\u0948?
```

I have spring-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
         <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />

    </bean>
```

I am using maven,So,In **Pom.xml** I have:

```
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
```

In my **jsp** page I have:

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<section >
    <spring:message code="text"/> <spring:message code="text_hi"/>
</ssection>
```

But the message is showing as **question mark..(????)**.. why??

Comment: Is your webpage in UTF-8 (i.e. a META-INF tag with the appropriate charset). You might want to configure a `CharacterEncodingFilter` as the first filter and force the encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638284/spring-mvc-response-encoding-issue

Comment: It should work actually as per the steps you followed. Try putting `<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>`

Comment: Yes you are right..Thank you..@ M. Deinum ,@ Parth Trivedi ,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22297858/gujarati-font-not-displayed-correctly/23446761#23446761

Comment: You can also instruct your application-server i.e Apache tomcat or so to use UTF-8. In JSP's, you might require to mention encoding as UTF-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually gujarati,hindi etc. fonts are in `utf-8` format. If you are using **Hindi** then in your html page following line should be there.

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
```

But you should remove other specifications like if you are using jsp page than

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

line should be removed because you are specifying in meta tag. You need only meta tag.